# Multiple PowerShell Scripts Writing to Same File

Tags: powershell

I have a condition that kicks off a PowerShell script to append a short string to a text file. This condition can fire rapidly, so the file is being written multiple times by the same script. Additionally, a separate script is importing from that text file in batches (less frequently).

Whenever the condition fires very rapidly, I get the error: "The process can not access the file 'file_name' because it is being used by another process." When I do the same append in Python (my main language), I don't get the same error, but I could use some help fixing this in PowerShell.

```
$action          = $args[0]
$output_filename = $args[1]
$item            = $args[2]

if ($action -eq 'direct'){
  $file_path = $output_filename
  $sw = New-Object -typename System.IO.StreamWriter($file_path, "true")
  $sw.WriteLine($item)
  $sw.Close() }
```

I have also tried the following instead of StreamWriter, but apparently the performance is weak for Add-Content and Out-File (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2010/01/04/add-content-and-out-file-are-not-for-performance.aspx):

```
out-file -Append -FilePath $file_path -InputObject $item }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might try something like this:

```
while ($true)
{
  Try {
        [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file_path).close()
        Add-Content -FilePath $file_path -InputObject $item
        Break
      }

    Catch {}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the Try/Catch with a Break for the solution. I should note, though, that I still used StreamWriter, since it's supposedly much faster.